# iOS: how do I know if I'm still connected to oprators's cellular network

Tags: ios

My iPhone is connected to cellular network and my own WiFi. If I go to the basement I'm still connected to wifi, by cellular connection goes down. How can I know that the cellular connection is active or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need "Reachability". Apple have provided it since the early days of the SDK, there is a link to a version by Tony Miller in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1625206/189804) and it is also part of the highly recommended [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) [(another relevant answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035987/189804). It will tell you whether you have any connection and what kind it is.