# AFNetworking Reachability Return FALSE value?

Tags: ios7, reachability, afnetworking-2

I have internet connection and can browsing with browser.

Here is my codes to check `Reachability` with `AFNetworking`.

```
- (BOOL)connected {
    return [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable;
}
```

And In ViewDidLoad

```
BOOL isOnline = [self connected];

    if(isOnline == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }
```

It's only showing `NO` and i don't know why is it?

Is there easiest way to check `Reachability` with `AFNetworking`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess `startMonitoring` isn't called, try to do the below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
      ....
     [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];   
}
```

Comment: Anyway it should be there bro, but it is weird it works fine, try to register for changes, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20035987/1262634.

Comment: When i test with these code , it's even doesn't show NSLog bro. [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
    }];

Comment: I also added #import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h". What do i need?

Comment: @Yahiko do test on the real device? try to turn off wireless, switch to cellular data then back to wireless etc..

Answer (score 1):

If  [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21965581/2735358) is not solving your issue,
then your problem might be due to calling `[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable` while it is in the middle of '`startMonitoring`' process where it would always return `NO`.

I had the same issue. I was calling web service while `AFNetworkReachabilityManager` had not finished monitoring process and was returning `reachable = NO` although I had working internet connection.

```
- (void) callWebService {
    NSLog(@"Calling Webservice...");

    if ([AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable == NO) {
        NSLog(@"%@", kErrorNoInternet);
        return;
    }

    // Now, proceed to call webservice....
}
```

So, to solve this I did a trick. Called web service after some delay (in this example 0.05 sec).

**Before:**

```
[self callWebService];
```

**Output:**[image]

**After:**

```
[self performSelector:@selector(callWebService) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3]; // you can set delay value as per your choice
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can see from the output, the time difference is hardly **0.05 sec** (exact value 0.048 sec).

Hope this will help.

Comment: You can also check if networkReachabilityStatus == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown. If status is Unknown then you can assume that network can be reachable and make a request

Answer (score 0):

instead of waiting you can use blocks just to make sure that your web service will be only called when network is available.

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager]startMonitoring];

[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager]setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status)
{
    if (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN || status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi) 
{

        // connected. you can call your web service here

    }else
{
        // internet disconnected
    }
}];
```