# AFnetwork reachability manager is always giving false results

Tags: macos, afnetworking

I am checking reachability to a particular ip address. It always returns unknown. below is what i am doing

```
AFNetworkReachabilityManager *addressCheck=[AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForAddress:@"192.168.1.45"];
    [addressCheck startMonitoring];
    NSLog(@"%hhd",addressCheck.reachable);
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[addressCheck localizedNetworkReachabilityStatusString]];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);

    NSLog(@"%@",addressCheck.localizedNetworkReachabilityStatusString);
```

Is this the right way to use. Or what wlse i can do it function properly. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the phone connected via wifi?

Comment: No connected to ethernet. I am working this on MAC OSX Device not on iphone.

Comment: Huh?  You mean simulator?

Comment: I am trying to check connectivity of that particular address from my MAC. the Application i am developing for is OSX not iphone.

Comment: OK.  That IP address responds to `ping`?

Comment: Yes, i am able to ping to that particular address from my terminal. I want to check this programatically in objective c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118186/discussion-between-syammala-and-droppy).

Comment: I'm not sure you're using it correctly. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035917/setting-up-reachability-with-afnetworking-2-0).